# Bind Java objects to ruby hashes

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Is there a way to create ruby value objects or hashes from java objects in jruby application ? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you read this page including some the links at the bottom? https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you are trying to achieve, but to convert a Java object into a ruby hash, you could do something like this:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'YourJavaClass'

a = YourJavaClass.new
hash = {}
a.java_class.fields.each{ |var| hash[var.name] = var.value(a) }
p hash
```

This assumes that the instance variables are accessible (`public`).  If they are not, you may need to make them accessible with something like:

```
a.java_class.declared_fields.each{ |var| var.accessible = true; hash[var.name] = var.value(a) }
```

(Note that this time it uses `declared_fields`)

Comment: thanks declared_fields works fine but I need totally ruby native hash, but in this way values can be such for example "createDatetime"=>#<Java::JavaUtil::Date:0x34a205d1>,

I  need to get all properties that have accessors to hash wich should have only ruby type values   .

Answer (score 2):

Names and Beans Convention gives us next opportunity for properties with accessors

```
def java_to_hash(java_obj)
    hash = {}
    java_obj.methods.grep(/get_/).each do |accessor|

      if accessor.eql? "get_class" then
        next
      end

      #get_user_name => user_name
      method_name = accessor[4..-1]

      if java_obj.respond_to?(method_name)
        hash[method_name.to_sym] = java_obj.send(accessor.to_sym)
      end
    end
    hash
end
```

Comment: That almost worked for me. I had to change the one conditional to: next if 'get_class' == accessor.try(:to_s)